# Python Application Executable

Tags: python

How we can create an Installable Package of Large Python Project ?  Is it advisable to convert the application as .EXE and install on Linux or Windows OS ? For example the .NET C# applications are being packaged as .MSI (Installable). In the same way how the Python Application can be deployed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create exe first and then create setup file with inno setup.

https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

you can find download links and usage from this site

you can use pyinstaller for exe